# T-SQL C# like lock

Tags: c#, t-sql, locking

In C# we can make a set of operations atomic using locks:

```
lock (syncLock)
{
    // Do something 1
    // Do something 2
    // ...
}
```

Now in `T-SQL` I want the same with a row. I should do some calculations and I want no change to the row until my calculations are finished. I know that the lock should be minimized and I did so.

Also the whole operation is read (no write) so there's no need for a transaction.

```
LOCK
SELECT statement on a single row
// Some calculations here...
IF ... RETURN
End of LOCK
```

I know about `ROWLOCK` and I can use it with my select statement. But I need the lock for calculation lines also. Is there something like `C#` brackets in `T-SQL` or `BEGIN LOCK`, `END LOCK` just like Monitor enter/exit ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at sp_getapplock:

http://web.archive.org/web/20140103030643/http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SQLExamples/Wiki/View.aspx?title=GetAppLock&referringTitle=Home

http://clay.lenharts.net/blog/2008/01/28/the-sp_getapplock-secret/

Comment: Afraid the first link is broken

Comment: @SteveC - updated, I recommend the http://web.archive.org for this sort of problems.

Answer (score 5):

BEGIN TRANSACTION TranName;

..your stuff

COMMIT TRANSACTION TranName;

Comment: You say `TRANSACTION` here works as a lock (the row would not be affected outside while the code is running) although the whole operation is just reading ?!